# What if connection is not explicitly closed using php amqplib?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, connection, php-amqplib

Suppose, in my php script, I have opened a connection to rabbitmq using php-amqplib client. And after publishing message, I dont explicitely close the channel and connection.

I dont see any timeout in rabbitmq config for connections. What happens to the connection? Does it remained open for no time?

Comment: How are you executing the php script? Via the `php` command or in a web server like Apache?

Comment: I am using apache as web server

Answer (score 0):

When running PHP in a web server, all resources (not just those related to `php-amqplib`) are released at the end of an HTTP request. This includes any channels or connections.

Comment: Thanks Luke. What if I execute my php script through CLI? Whal will happen with rabbitmq connections then?

Comment: These are basic PHP questions that are not specific to `php-amqplib`. The connections established by `php-amqplib` will be as long-running as their execution environment.